# How to kill a java process by name in python?

Tags: python, process

I am trying to kill java process with name "MyClass" using below python script :

```
import os
os.system("kill $(ps aux | grep 'MyClass' | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $2}')")
```

But this gives me output as below and the process is still running

```
sh: 1: kill: Usage: kill [-s sigspec | -signum | -sigspec] [pid | job]... or
kill -l [exitstatus]
512
```

I know that the $ sign is the problem here but do not know how to make this work.

Any help/hint is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: How about os.system("kill `ps aux | grep 'MyClass' | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $2}'`)?

Comment: @kuro that gives error. Thanks though.

Comment: May be because SO changed the comment. Add '`' before and after the highlighted portion

Answer (score 1):

```
def terminate_java_process(process_name):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["jps"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    (out, err) = proc.communicate()
    processes = {}
    for line in out.split(b"\n"):
        try:
            process_name=str(line, 'utf-8').split(' ')[1]
        except:
            continue
        process_id= str(line, 'utf-8').split(' ')[0]
        processes[process_name] = process_id
    
    os.system("kill -s TERM 82220")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have another way:

I am fetching all the processes, by looping each one I'm taking the required one and if it is found just kill them.

> I am making use of these concept to find out how many processes are running for the same client, for the same category.

```
# this will fetch the processes in stdout var
processes = Popen(['ps', '-ef'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, error = processes.communicate()

for line in stdout.splitlines():

    if (line.__contains__("Process_name to check")):

       pid = int(line.split(None, 1)[0])
       os.kill(pid, signal.SIGKILL)
```